# Create observable, subscribe to it and return it

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming

I have a following problem:
I need to send POST request to acquire token from oAuth. Later I want to create user context via another service. But still I need to preserve Observable, because I would like to react to response on component.

Is this a proper way to do it?

```
login(username, password): Observable<any> {
  let response$ = this._http.post(params)
    .map((response: Response) => response.json());

  response$.subscribe(v => this._userService.doSmth());

  return response$;
}
```

**EDIT:**

I found another way to do it based on @Maximus response. That's right - I want to make only one request. So I wrote something like this:

```
let response$ = this._http.post(data)
  .map((response: Response) => response.json());

let user$ = new Subject<User>();

response$.subscribe(v =>
  this._userService.createNewSession(v) // returns observable
    .subscribe(u => user$.next(u))
);

return user$.asObservable();
```

Is this ok?

Comment: _But still I need to preserve Observable, because I would like to react to response on component._ - why? what do you plan to do with it?

Comment: I want a component to react on "user logged event".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
let response$ = this._http.post(params).map((response: Response) => response.json());
```

sets up an observable chain which doesn't do anything by itself. As soon as someone subscribes to it it will send http request. This is what happens here:

```
response$.subscribe(v => this._userService.doSmth());
```

But the `response$` points to that chain, not the value returned. If someone else subscribes to the `response$` again, the new request will be issued.

If you want to allow subscription to the `response$` and want other parts of the system to be able to access the value, you should use `AsyncSubject`:

```
let subject = new AsyncSubject();
let response$ = this._http.post(data).map((response: Response) => response.json()).subscribe(subject);
response$.subscribe(v => this._userService.createNewSession(v));

return response$;
```

Comment: @ŁukaszSzcześniak, so what is your question now?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to ask. I just want to know if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: @ŁukaszSzcześniak, actually, `AsyncSubject` is a better option. I updated the code. Let me know if it helped.

Comment: I assume you are right, although I have to learn more about subjects. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @ŁukaszSzcześniak, see [this explanation](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#asyncsubject).